# Ricoh Aficio SP 100su E

Tags: linux, drivers, printing, cups

After installing a Ricoh Aficio SP 100su E printer (it does scanning as well),
I've tried a tenth of the GDI and PCL (5e/6) generic and Ricoh drivers without any success.

I've learned from Ricoh that this printer uses GDI standard... but these drivers don't seem to work. No errors occur, but no pages are printed out.

Has anybody succeeded to print under Linux with this one?

Answer (score 5):

I also have this printer, so I wrote a driver which you can use with it.

This is a GDI-printer. It uses PJL with JBIG1 images to interact with host.

You can download this driver from my github account, [madlynx/ricoh-sp100](https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100).

Installation instructions:

1. Copy pstoricohddst-gdi to cups' filters directory (usually */usr/lib/cups/filter*).
2. Install *jbigkit* package (*jbitkit-bin* in Ubuntu)
3. Make sure it is executable by *lp* user.
4. Add printer through CUPS' web interface, click 'Choose file' at driver select page and select supplied .PPD file, continue to setup.

Comment: did not work for me. When I select the PPD file and go "Forward", I get "There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'client-error-not-possible'".

Comment: you sir are awesome for making this github repo and making my printer work! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I Bought this Ricoh SP100 laser Printer and was amazingly dissapointed to discover that it did not work with my Ubuntu OS. So I followed the advice here and verily that did print the test page for me.

Step1: Download the zipfile from https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100
        Unzip it.

step2: Open command line and do this:
                 sudo cp Downloads/ricoh-sp100-master/pstoricohddst-gdi usr/lib/cups/filter
enter your password to make the copy paste happen

step3: open synaptic package manager and search there for 'jbigkit' install it.(if you don't know how to install from package manager please take help of the web)

step4: Now close everything and add the printer. When it comes to the driver section. Add the file manually for myself the file was RICOH_Aficio_SP_100.ppd already in the unziped file.

Almost done. Try the test print.... PEACE.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. it works!

Answer (score 0):

What Linux distribution is this? Everything up to date? What sort of printing system does it use (What does `man lpq` say? If the last line includes CUPS, it is CUPS. Others I don't know offhand.)?

My printing system here gets tied into knots sometimes, restarting the print system unwedges it most of the time.

That printer isn't listed at [OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org), the one with a similar name I found (SP 1000S, can't say if it is really similar) is listed as only partially supported. In any case, that database is maintained by volunteers sending in data, and is missing much information.

Does the manufacturer say anything on Linux support? Does it work on Mac OS X (if it doesn't, it is a safe bet it won't work on Linux)?